# Android sensors and loop

Tags: java, android, sensors

```
public void onCreate()
{
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensorManager
                .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
        while(true);
}
```

-

```
 public void onCreate()
    {
            new lt().start()
            while(true);
    }
class lt extends Thread
{
    public void run()
    {
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensorManager
                .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
        while(true);
    }
}
```

If i insert the while, the light sensor doesn't take any light value. Same thing if i put this code (except for the while) inside another thread. Why? Shouldn't the listener work in backgorund? I need to wait a bit (i'll replace that while whti something else) after the sensor registration before checking the light value. How can i do?

Comment: `while(true);` will keep on running and its an never ending loop. YOu need to use some kinda of `Timer Class` if you want to wait. See [--> Timer Class Overview](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) **OR** [-->CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

Comment: I just noticed a missing semicolon on the new lt().start() line. I'll assume that's a typo in the question, but that the line actually ends in a semicolon.

Comment: Yes, i copied the code before adding the ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You absolutely must NOT

```
 while(true);
```

in onCreate();

It ties up the main (UI) thread in Android.

=========================

Android runs an event loop.  The callback is scheduled to run in the event loop but it cannot run until control returns from onCreate().   Thus your program will hang until it gets an Application Not Responding error.

This: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html
Is a good place to start reading about the mechanism underneath your Android code.

==================

The code that uses a thread is worse because the main thread is still hung in onCreate(), but now you are trying to schedule a callback for the IT thread, but it is not running an event loop.  (Not to mention that it, too, is now hung in a while(true); )

---

Try this:

```
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();
    setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);
    [other activity initialization code]
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensorManager
            .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
}
```

And read this which gives an example: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html

Comment: So you are telling me that even if i create a new thread, i'm still inside onCreate()?

Comment: The new thread is created in the new IT.start(); line.  The next statement, the infinite while loop, is still running in the old thread, so yes you are still running onCreate().

Comment: I still can't understand this. Why are they in the same thread? Can i do something if i use an asynctask instead of a thread?

Comment: I started the thread from the onCreate. I put the a sleep (the while of the question) in the thread after i created an asynctask that registers the listeners. It works but i don't know if it's a nice solution.